# Javascript site failing when using loops or many functions calling other ones

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I am currently trying to write an AI which then is going to play the game "2048". That AI is currently working in theory, but when I run the code, Chrome tells me that the side is not responding. When I change the code in a way that there is no loop active, it totally works (well it "works" means that I only have the code with no loops meaning the code telling the side how she has to look like and the main Game, in which the loops are somehow working)

I have no Idea, what I am doing wrong, I have tried by removing some parts of the Code, and it works when I remove the loops in the `AIRunNow()` or the `AI()` function.

In the following link you can get every one of my three files, the css-file is more or less empty.

The code for the game itself is copied from GitHub.

https://github.com/JackOBIsReal/2048-AI-not-working

If you find mistakes I made in the english parts of my codes, I yould be very pleased If you could correct them too as I am a german student, and I don't want to have those errors in there, but this part isn't essential for my code to work.

I haven't yet finished the code for the AI, but I first want to make the code work this far because when something isn't working when I add the code of the AI I can directly see that the errors come from there, but if I added that code now I wouldn't know if it is the error's source or if it is somewhere else.
I hope you understand what i mean...

Thanks to everyone looking at my problem, even if he/she can't help me.

Comment: for one, i'd add a `php` tag to this question - i've no idea how `php` deals with this stuff.  With regards to your `JS` though, at what point does it fail when you're debugging through it?  _Have_ you debugged through it?  You getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: `That AI is currently working in theory` I'd posit that it doesn't actually work. My guess is that it goes in an infinite loop. The code seems too big to easily spot why that would be and would also require knowledge of how it's working and how it's supposed to be working. I'd advise debugging and stepping through the methods and/or adding some logging to loops to see when/where does the code get stuck.

Comment: The problem was that I used `=` instead of `==` in a loop as argument, causing everything to not work at all from the beginning. I changed it now, and now the console finally tells me the ten reference-errors...